# Why is my 'clickable' <img> covered (and therefore not clickable)? And by what is it covered?

Tags: html, css

So, I had a difficult time trying to figure out why a couple of my links were not clickable.  I finally figured out that they just needed a 'higher' z-index.  I don't really understand why they needed that in order to work though.  I'm figuring out (through google-research) that some elements can be 'covered' by other elements.  I don't understand how that happened in my code, in particular, and kind of still confused about that whole concept of some elements 'covering' others.  Can anyone explain?  Here's the relevant HTML and CSS, respectively: (I had trouble with the elements within  )

HTML:

```
<section id="nav_images">

<a href="scum_scoop.html" title="Info about Scum"><img id="skull" class="reflectBelow" src="ScumSkull.jpg" alt="Click for scoop" height="94" width="94"/></a>

<a href="scum_staff.html" title="Meet our Staff"><img id="staff" class="reflectBelow" src="ScumStaff.jpg" alt="Click for staff" height="94" width="94"></a>

<a href="scum_sermons.html" title="Hear some Sermons"><img id="bulbs" class="reflectBelow" src="ScumBulbs.jpg" alt="Click for sermons" height="94" width="94"></a>

</section>

<aside id="don8">

<p id="don_P"><a href="scum_donate.html" title="Click to Donate">Make a Donation to Scum</a></p>

<a href="scum_donate.html" title="Click to Donate"><img id="donate" src="donate.gif" alt="Donate button" height="47" width="147"></a>

</aside>


<aside id="slogans">

<h3>Top Five Rejected Scum of the Earth Slogans</h3>

<p  id="slogan_5" class="slogan">5. Emerging from the emergent church</p>

<p class="slogan">4. Our congregation can kick your congregation's ass</p>

<p class="slogan">3. Same old evangelical crap, different package</p>

<p class="slogan">2. Come to see the crazy bathrooms, stay for a sermon</p>

<p class="slogan">1. And you thought mega-churches sucked</p>

</aside>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-color:#000000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:100%;
width:100%;
}

main
{
display:block;
max-width:700px;
margin:40px auto 300px auto;
height:650px;
}

img
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:none;
float:left; /* Gets rid of space between images */
}

#don8
{
clear:left;
float:right;
position:relative;
top:50px;
width:250px;
height:140px;
border-left:13px solid red;
}

#don_P
{
width: 60px;
position:relative;
top:-10px;
left:60px;
text-align:center;
z-index:2;
}

#don_P a:link, a:hover, a:focus
{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}

#donate
{
position:relative;
top:-10px;
left:20px;
z-index:2;
}

#slogans
{
clear:left;
position:relative;
top:50px;
left:35px;
/* border-right: 5px solid red; */
}

.slogan
{
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
line-height:160%;
}

#slogan_5
{
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows a nice picture of what it looks like when the 'layer' is visible and overlapping another layer.  This 'overlapping' will happen primarily when you force how the browser should render an item by specifying the coordinates where the item should be placed on the page.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index

A convenient way to observe how the browser has layered your HTML, you can use Google Chrome developer tools.  Open the page in Google Chrome browser, then Right click on the element in question and select "Inspect Element".  This will give you a view of the boundaries of that element.

Pretty much all modern browsers have this 'element inspector' feature somewhere.  Firefox also has this feature in their dev tools, but also has a fancy tool that can also do this, but in 3D:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View

Comment: Thanks for the resources.  I'm still lost. Before I added a z-index of '2' to both #donate and #don_P they were visible to me, but apparently not to the browser (or something), because I could not click on them.  So, something was covering them.  I just don't know what, or how you would find that out so that you could make sure to give them a more positive z-index so that they would rise above the rest and work as links. (I couldn't figure that out from using "Inspect Element".)

Comment: I've uploaded some screenshots to imgur.com:

  http://i.imgur.com/XB7de44.png
  http://i.imgur.com/jxIrxAv.png
  http://i.imgur.com/mGe24vn.png

Note how the first 2 images I'm highlighting the 'slogans' aside, and the 3rd image I'm highlighting the 'don8' aside.  The highlight shows that the 'slogans' runs to the end of the page.  Although Chrome appears to allow me to click the links on the right, some other browsers (because of the overlay of the 'aside' tags) may not respect that and will possibly prevent you from clicking the links to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some CSS, your links are not covered. Their color turn white on :hover.

```
#don_P a:link, a:hover, a:focus { color: white; }
```

Comment: I don't know if it would make a difference, but here is the full HTML & CSS at JSfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5dxn5eg6/1/

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your code and I see the overlap.

Your problem is that this:

```
<aside id="slogans">
<h3>Top Five Rejected Scum of the Earth Slogans</h3>
<p  id="slogan_5" class="slogan">5. Emerging from the emergent church</p>
<p class="slogan">4. Our congregation can kick your congregation's ass</p>
<p class="slogan">3. Same old evangelical crap, different package</p>
<p class="slogan">2. Come to see the crazy bathrooms, stay for a sermon</p>
<p class="slogan">1. And you thought mega-churches sucked</p>
</aside>
```

is appearing on top of

```
<aside id="don8">
<p id="don_P"><a href="scum_donate.html" title="Click to Donate">Make a Donation to Scum</a></p>
<a href="scum_donate.html" title="Click to Donate"><img id="donate" src="donate.gif" alt="Donate button" height="47" width="147"></a>
</aside>
```

Here is an analogy. Imagine if you have two sheets of paper stacked on top of each other. When you bring your pen down on them, it only touches the top one.

This is the same for your mouse pointer.  When you click on the page, you click on the top element.  In your case, the top element isn't the link so you can't click on it.

There are two solutions to this problem.

1. Limit the width the the overlapping object so it no longer overlaps.
2. Give your elements z-indexes and position the link on top.

If you are unclear how z-indexes work here is a good link:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

To put it simply, elements with a higher z-index are positioned above elements with lower one.  If there is no z-index, the browser just decides.